# curl uses POST for all requests after redirect

Tags: http, redirect, curl

According to the documentation and some similar questions on SO curl should follow a redirect using GET method, unless --post30x is specified as a parameter. However that's the result of my testing

```
curl -kvv -b /tmp/tmp.BEo6w3GKDq -c /tmp/tmp.BEo6w3GKDq -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -L https://localhost/api/v1/resource

> POST /api/v1/resource HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=AB59F2FD09D38EDBAACB726CF212EA2E; JSESSIONID=743FD68B520840094B6D283A81CF3CFA
> Accept: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1    
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
< Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: https://testserver.int/api/v1/resource
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 08:41:05 GMT
<
> POST /api/v1/resource HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: testserver.int
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=1tcxpkul4qyqh1hycpf9insei9
> Accept: application/json
```

I would expect the second request to actually be using GET instead of POST.

[curl's man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) says:

> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for
>   example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if
>   the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any
>   other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same
>   unmodified method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET
>   after a 30x response by using the dedicated options for that:
>   --post301, --post302 and --post303.

Unfortunatelly that's not what I'm seeing and there is no option for --get30x.

So my question is - how to make curl follow a redirect response (301/302/303) with a GET request to the Location as it is written in the documentation?

I've tested it with curl/7.29.0 as well as curl/7.50.3.

Comment: I like your article, but what is the question?

Comment: I've updated the... article with a question at the end :) sorry for not making it clearer at the beginning

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Problem:** You are telling curl to do that with your use of -X POST. As the man page section for -X explains this:

```
The method string you set with -X, --request will be used for all requests, which
if you for example use -L, --location may cause unintended side-effects when curl
doesn't change request method according to the HTTP 30x response codes - and
similar.
```

**Fix:** Remove the -X POST from your command line. Use -d "" instead to send an empty post that will adjust accordingly to the proper method after redirect.

**More:** Explanation and rant in my blog post [unnecessary use of curl -X](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/).

Comment: Thanks, it works. It seems a little counter intuitive to provide an empty body instead of just say -X POST, but indeed I missed that part of the man page.

Comment: So if I have `PUT` or `PATCH` rather than `POST`, I’m out of luck?

Comment: Is there any solution or workaround when using other methods like PUT or PATCH like @VasiliyFaronov mentioned? I am writing a library around curl and don't know how to handle these.

Comment: When using the `-d ""` instead of `-X POST` I can no longer see any output from the `curl` command. It works, I can see that the request is handled by the application's API, but why am I not seeing any output?