# curl: Redirect from post route to get route

Tags: express, curl

I have an express app and I want to be able to redirect a post request to a get request.

Here is the app:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/get-route', function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.post('/post-route', function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('Home Page!\n');
}); 

app.listen(3001);
```

and here are my results with curl:

```
steve@Dell ~ $ curl http://localhost:3001/
Home Page!
steve@Dell ~ $ curl -L http://localhost:3001/get-route
Home Page!
```

In the curl request below it sais it is Redirecting to / but I do not understand why it does not display the `Home Page!` message.

```
steve@Dell ~ $ curl -X POST http://localhost:3001/post-route
Found. Redirecting to /
```

I thought the -L option might work but that gives an error:

```
steve@Dell ~ $ curl -L -X POST http://localhost:3001/post-route
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be great to have an idea of how I can redirect my post request to the get request using curl.

Since first asking this question I have noticed that I can get what I want using HTTPie:

```
steve@Dell ~ $ http --form --follow POST localhost:3001/post-route
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2019 18:03:14 GMT
ETag: W/"b-OVE2GcFhwNv2PpVDFXfoBIbNry4"
X-Powered-By: Express

Home Page!
```

I would still like to be able to use curl if possible to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your original code above you don't specify a status code with the redirect from the post to the get route. Express will send a default status code of 302 which means the browser will get back the new location '/' and the GET method. All should be good...

Except when using curl's -X option you are unintentionally telling curl to make all requests to that route (including redirects) with the original method specified.

So curl is getting back the redirect location and correct method but is then attempting to POST to a GET route per your instructions. Using the -X option is kind of a general forced solution to problems that have specific solutions available.

As answered in the link below in this situation you would want to use ***curl's -d option*** as that is one of the intended ways for sending a POST request with curl.

[curl uses POST for all requests after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890172/curl-uses-post-for-all-requests-after-redirect)

***TLDR:*** `curl -L -d POST http://localhost:3001/post-route` should work.